# Using Twitter Bootstrap with a Rails 2.3 app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass, ruby-on-rails-2, jammit

We have a Rails 2.3 app with SASS and want to use Twitter Bootstrap. We use Jammit to package our JavaScript and CSS (after being generated by Compass).

Is there an easy way (or instructions) on how to integrate the Twitter Bootstrap (and LESS) with an app like ours? I can only seem to find examples with Rails 3.x asset pipeline...

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this...

First, I downloaded the source of [sass-twitter-bootstrap](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap) to get the Sass converted Less files.

Next, I put all of the Sass into the app/stylesheets/bootstrap directory and the main bootstrap and responsive files in app/stylesheets.

Then, I put all of the JavaScript files into the public/javascripts/bootstrap directory.

Finally, I created a new stylesheet and JavaScript package for Jammit in the assets.yml file.

Since I was going to slowly convert my app over to Twitter bootstrap a few controllers at a time, I created a new app/views/layouts/bootstrap.html.erb layout.